# How to avoid TDateTime Data Rounding

Tags: delphi, datetime, firemonkey

I am writing column and cell classes for FMX `TGrid` that will contain `TCalendarEdit` and `TTimeEdit` instances in every cell. Everything works fine except the proper processing of changes done in these child controls.

```
type
  TFMTValue<T> = record
    FieldValue: T;
    Modified: boolean;
    Appended: boolean;
    Deleted: boolean;
  end;

  TDateTimeCell = class(TStyledControl)
    private
      FDate_Time: TFMTValue<TDateTime>;
      procedure SetDateTime(const Value: TFMTValue<TDateTime>);
      function GetDateTime: TFMTValue<TDateTime>;
    protected
      procedure SetData(const Value: TValue); override;
    public
      property Date_Time: TFMTValue<TDateTime> read GetDateTime write SetDateTime;
    ...   
   end;
...     
  function TDateTimeCell.GetDateTime: TFMTValue<TDateTime>;
    begin
      FDate_Time.Modified := (FDate_Time.Modified) or
        (FDate_Time.FieldValue <> FCalendarEdit.Date +
         + FTimeEdit.Time);
      FDate_Time.FieldValue := FCalendarEdit.Date + FTimeEdit.Time;
      Result := FDate_Time;
    end;

    procedure TDateTimeCell.SetData(const Value: TValue);
    begin
      Date_Time := Value.AsType<TFMTValue<TDateTime>>;
      inherited SetData(TValue.From<TDateTime>(FDate_Time.FieldValue));
      ApplyStyling;
    end;

    procedure TDateTimeCell.SetDateTime(const Value: TFMTValue<TDateTime>);
    begin
      FDate_Time := Value;
      FCalendarEdit.Date := DateOf(FDate_Time.FieldValue);
      FTimeEdit.Time := TimeOF(FDate_Time.FieldValue);
      FDate_Time.FieldValue:=FCalendarEdit.Date + FTimeEdit.Time; //this line helps but not in all cases
    end;
```

The idea is that data is assigned via `TGrid` `OnGetValue` event handler. Both date and time are displayed. The user activity is catched and `Modified` flag is set. The problem is that this flag is set to true sometimes even without any user activities. I suspect it is due to the rounding of time part of TDateTime. There are no other ways the code assignes values to `FCalendarEdit.Date` and `FTimeEdit.Time`.

How can I properly compare the data stored in `FCalendarEdit.Date` and `FTimeEdit.Time` with that stored in `FDate_Time.FieldValue`?

**Appended**

Setting the flag in this way does not resolve the issue.

```
  FDate_Time.Modified := (FDate_Time.Modified) or
    (DateOf(FDate_Time.FieldValue) <> FCalendarEdit.Date) or
    (TimeOf(FDate_Time.FieldValue)<> FTimeEdit.Time);
```

**Appended 2.** On a valued advice of @Ken-White.
If we replace the comparison line by

```
FDate_Time.Modified := (FDate_Time.Modified) or
(not SameDateTime(FDate_Time.FieldValue,
 FCalendarEdit.Date + FTimeEdit.Time));
```

It works fine. So the TDataTime comparison must be done by this function only.

Comment: Well, if `FDate_Time.FieldValue <> FCalendarEdit.Date + FTimeEdit.Time` then the value really has changed. Beyond that I cannot work out what your code is trying to do. A [mcve] would be nice. Perhaps you also need to do a bit more debugging so that you understand what is going on.

Comment: TDateTime is a floating point (double) value. You can see if they're the same to within one millisecond using `DateUtils.SameDateTime`, but if they're a MS or more apart they're not the same date/time value. What do you consider the accuracy that you need to use for them being equal with the database value?

Comment: @David, thank you,  I have localized the problem and appended the post. Please, kindly, have a look.

Comment: @Ken-White, thank you, I have changed the code to `SameDateTime` and appended the post. Please, kindly, have a look. I need only 1 minute precision.

Comment: That edit doesn't really help me. I don't understand why you won't make a [mcve]. I never understand why people don't do that.

Comment: @KenWhite, Thank you for your advice. The `SameDateTime` works, the ordinary comparison - not. Please, post an answer, so that I could accept it.

Comment: The conclusion you draw in your latest edit doesn't seem to get to the bottom of the issue. This seems like a typically fuzzy approach to floating point. If I were you I'd want to understand this issue properly. Comparing floating point values for equality is fine. So long as you create the two values the same way. It saddens me that so many people give up and stuff an arbitrary fuzz factor on comparisons. Of course using floating point for dates and times is a poor design, but it is what it is unfortunately.

Comment: @asd-tm - your "Appended 2" example contains an error:  SameDateTime( **DATEOF(X)**, Date + **TIME**) is bound to be false if TIME is non-zero (i.e. not midnight - 00:00:00).  This is because of the use of DATEOF() which will truncate the FieldValue you are passing.  As a result this example does not help identify or confirm any problem with floating point issues.

Comment: Why won't you just make a [mcve]? You've got an opportunity to learn something here. It looks rather like you don't care about learning and just want to try stuff at random until it appears that you might have solved your problem. And probably have not. And certainly not gained any understanding.

Comment: @David I have edited the question. I could do it only after I have got an answer.

Comment: I reverted that edit. That destroyed the question. It's too late now. Ken's given you an answer. You accepted it. Your proposed edit removes anything of use. It doesn't seem to me that you are interested in understanding the issue in depth and are content with a fuzzy solution. That's fine, it's your choice. Not the way I would do it, but that's just fine.

Comment: I don't want to humiliate anybody. I'd really like to help you learn more about floating point arithmetic. Are you interested in that?

Comment: @David Yes, I am, otherwise I would not have reedited the question making it more interesting for the future visitors and helping the forum. And you insist on keeping a mistake of a non-professional and don't allow to change the question to the better - this is the humiliation. Many non-professionals simply can not shorten the example to three lines of code before they get new knowledge.

Comment: You were not making the question better. Your edit made it worse. Because the edit your proposed edit only told half the story. It asked, "why does `a <> b` evaluate to `True`?" But you did not give details of where `a` and `b` came from. So your edit actually broke the question. If you can make a `[mcve]` then I'm sure that I, or others, can enlighten you as to why your code was failed, and what possible options you have. Beyond the answer that you already accepted.

Comment: I expect that the key to understanding this will lie in this expression: `DateOf(dt) + TimeOf(dt) = dt` Whilst you might hope that would always evaluate to `True`, it won't. I'm sure if we could cut your code down to something that focused on that expression, then there'd be some enlightenment.

Comment: @David, I hope this edit will help the community.

Comment: I give up. I don't think that edit helps at all. I'd like to help you, but you aren't making it possible for me to do so. If you change your mind, just post an [mcve] and let me know.

Comment: @David, Feel free to do anything you wish with the question. You judge the people form the point of view of a top-level IT professional and I respect you for that. But the majority of visitors of this forum are not professionals (at least not in the IT sphere). We simply don't understand what kind of question do you desire to have here. And on the other hand you don't understand that other people may think in a different way than you.

Comment: One last time, make an [mcve] and I'll try to explain. Why don't you want to do that? Did you follow the link yet?

Comment: @David, The same question asked in the other way.

Comment: Simply put, don't split apart date and time and then try to reassemble. Store the original date/time.

Comment: Which Delphi version? There are differences.

Comment: @Tom-Brunberg, I use Delphi XE5

Comment: @asd Your edits changed the question completely which was totally unfair on Ken. I put the question back in its original form. Edit to improve by all means, but please stay true to the form of the original. Don't change the code so grossly as to ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TDateTime` is of `type Double`, which means it's a floating point value, and therefore is subject to the usual issues of binary representation when doing comparisons for equality without specifying an acceptable delta (difference)..

Specifically for `TDateTime` values, you can use `DateUtils.SameDateTime` to compare equality down to less than one millisecond:

```
FDate_Time.Modified := (FDate_Time.Modified) or
           (not SameDateTime(FDate_Time.FieldValue, 
            FCalendarEdit.Date + FTimeEdit.Time));
```

Comment: *decimal precision* is somewhat misleading because the data type is *binary* rather than *decimal. The issues are less to do with comparisons, which are very well-defined, rather the issues are that arithmetical expressions that would be identical in true mathematics can be different in finite floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @David: OK. Feel free to add a link to the previous extensive answer you posted on that topic. It was much better than I could provide here in an answer to this question.

Comment: Floating point precision is not the issue in this case.  Rather it is a basic failure to appreciate that there is no compiler enforcement of discrete time and date values, only date/time values with variations in intended use and a resulting implementation error when those variations have been ignored.  You could also argue that the controls involved are not helping matters (at least, at worst actually faulty) by failing to "trim" the internal date/time values appropriately to their use in each case.

Comment: Despite the problems with the question as originally posted, it does not illustrate a very useful point, albeit not the one that it was thought to be.  i.e. the dangers of types named for a purpose and intent that is not reflected or enforced by the compiler.  For that reason I have upvoted the question as it currently stands and suggest it remains open, despite the earlier problems with it.

Comment: @Deltics: Thanks for your feedback (and your vote). In this case, testing for floating point equality without specifying an acceptable delta was in fact the issue, and specifying that delta (< 1 millisecond that is used by `SameDateTime`) resolves the issue. I never said it was an issue with *floating point precision*; it's an issue with expecting exact floating point equality when comparing two floating point values that are obtained by different means.

Comment: @Ken - what you call *an issue with expecting exact... etc* is exactly what I mean by *floating point precision issues*.  But the values in the code as posted are **not** obtained by different means so this isn't a factor.  What *does* happen is that the values are passed through the properties of some controls before the comparison.  If those controls behaved correctly w.r.t the "trimming" value involved, there would be no problem with the particular date+time in this case.  The issue is (arguably a flaw) in the controls, the OP's code and the mixing of TTime/TDate and TDateTime

Comment: Darn - I just noticed that I added a "not" in my previous comment.  The intended observation was that the question in its current state **does** illustrate a useful point!!  Too late to edit it to correct now though, so hence this clarification.

Comment: @Deltics: *the mixing of TTime/TDate and TDateTime* are precisely what I meant by *different means*. You and David are both reading the question "How do I copy a file?" and responding with a description of sectors, MFTs, NTFS, disk geometry, and other details, while the poster is looking for *use CopyFile()*. There is a specific question asked here, which deals with the code posted not working and finding a solution. The question didn't ask about how floating point numbers work. I chose to answer the question asked and not a rehash of the famous "What every computer programmer should know".

Comment: @Ken - You aren't making sense.  You seem to be saying you were not addressing the problem of the imprecision of floating point but this is **Exactly** what you address in the opening of your answer and in the presented solution.  I on the other hand make it plain that this is *not the problem in this case*.  I have now confirmed that the CalendarEdit1 control is the culprit with a very simple bug.  It has nothing what-so-ever to do with the way the values are being compared and everything to do with that bug (introduced in incorrect handling of the trimming of the value passed as "TDate").

Comment: @Ken redux - I have updated my answer with an explanation of the bug in **TCalendarEdit** and the workaround.  Using SameDateTime() has no effect in this case since the delta arising from the bug is 24 **HOURS** not sub-millisecond.  I take on board your point about labouring the details tho, so have removed the 'lesson' on TTime/TDate (which had nothing to do with the binary representation of double, by the way) even though it is still important.  Some of the relevant material remains however, to explain how this issue is in fact the cause of the bug in TCalendarEdit itself.

Comment: @Deltics Ken answered a different question to you. Ken answered the original question. The asker then accepted Ken's answer and changed the question completely. I tried to revert the edits but the asker insisted on changing the question. Whilst I have almost idelogical objections to fuzzing solutions when they are not needed, Ken's answer will make the asker's code behave as desired, and is true to the question that was asked.

Comment: @Deltics I put the question back to a form where Ken's answer matches.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in **TCalendarEdit** (a few actually) which is the underlying cause of your problem, but you can fix it with only a small change to your code.

## The Problem

The **TCalendarEdit** makes a number of crucial errors when it applies a new **Date** value.

A **TDate** type is actually just an ordinary **TDateTime** in which you are supposed to ignore the time portion.  Similarly a **TTime** is a **TDateTime** where you are supposed to ignore the date portion.

But you have to use these types correctly in your code - there is nothing that magically makes a **TTime** ignore the date or a **TDate** ignore the time.

For example, if you examine the constructor of the TCalendarEdit, you will see that it initialises the internal date/time to the current system date and time using Now, but truncates this to eliminate the time element:

```
Date := Trunc(Now);
```

So far so good.

But when you apply a new value via the **Date** property, it performs the following (simplified):

```
if Date <> Value then
  FDateTime := Value + Time;
```

*Both* of these lines of code contain serious bugs:

1. It compares the **Date** (property returning the Date value of the control) with the **Value** being assigned - *including any time value in that date/time*.  It should instead compare only the *date* part of the **Value**.
2. When assigning the new value to the internal date/time it adds **Time** to the **Value** you specified.

The first bug results in unnecessary changes to the internal property but is otherwise relatively innocuous.  The second bug however is far more serious and is what is causing your problem.

I presume that the intention of the author of the control was to leave the time portion of the internal date/time value unchanged.  However, the **Value** is not truncated, so it retains the time value specified in the assignment to the property.  To make matters even worse, there is no **Time** property on this control, so this in fact adds the current system time to whatever time is specified in **Value**.

## How This Affects Your Code and Test Case

Since your test case involved a time of midday - 12 hours - the result is that when you run this code in the afternoon, the **Date** of your **TCalendarEdit** is actually set to 25-Sep-2015 + 12 hours + *the time when the control was initialised*.

If you run the code in the morning, it seems to work because the time added results in a value that is still on the 25th Sep.

But when you run the code in the afternoon, the 12 hours are added to the current time and so the date rolls over **to the next day**!

With a more helpful diagnostic error message, or if you had inspected the properties in your code via the debugger, you would have seen this occurring.

```
DT := EncodeDate(2015, 9, 25) + EncodeTime(12, 0, 0, 0); 
CalendarEdit1.Date := DT;

ShowMessage(DateTimeToString(CalendarEdit1.Date));

// When executed at e.g. 9am, displays:  25 Sep 2015
// When executed at e.g. 1pm, displays:  26 Sep 2015
```

So the reason your comparison then fails is because the date is actually completely different!

If you had tried simply using **SameDateTime()** for the comparison it may have appeared to have worked if you tested it *in the morning* but your problem would have returned in the afternoon !!

## The Solution

You can work around these bugs in **TCalendarEdit** by ensuring that you respect the intended use of the property values yourself, assigning only those parts of the **DT** date/time value as appropriate in each case:

```
TimeEdit1.Time     := TimeOf(DT);
CalendarEdit1.Date := DateOf(DT);
```

Although not strictly necessary in the case of the **TTimeEdit**, this will prevent these bugs in **TCalendarEdit** from causing these problems and makes it clear in your code that you are aware of what is required (consider it self documenting code if you like).  :)

If you do not have **TimeOf()** and **DateOf()** functions in your version of Delphi, then the following is equivalent:

```
TimeEdit1.Time     := DT - Trunc(DT);
CalendarEdit1.Date := Trunc(DT);
```

You could of course write your own versions of **TimeOf()** and **DateOf()** based on this, to make the intention clearer.

## NOTE

There *are* precision complications arising from the floating point nature of date/time values in Delphi that could cause problems with direct comparisons with some specific values of date and time and for that reason it is highly recommended that you use the **SameDateTime()** function for performing such comparisons.

But this was absolutely **not** the cause of your problem in this case and **SameDateTime()** does **not** solve your problem.

**SameDateTime()** eliminates problems arising from differences in date/time values of less than 1 millisecond.  The difference in this case was 24 hours!

Worth noting is that the **TCalendarEdit** control was deprecated in XE7 and has been removed entirely from XE8.

Comment: *But this was not the cause of your problem in this case.* Almost certainly not so. Because the asker changed the question and in its current form it does not reflect the actual problem faced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice! (+1) I have appended the question. Hope it can be interesting.

Comment: @asd - I just updated the answer - the problem does involve the use of TDate and TTime but is actually a bug in the TCalendarEdit control which makes your code vulnerable to the problem.  You can work around it though:  see the updated answer.

Comment: @David - Although the original question had problems I suspect that the underlying cause of the problem was in fact the same since the TCalendarEdit control is **bound** to fail in this use case *at certain times of day!*.  The question as originally posted simply made it harder to see the true problem.  The current form of the question more accurately reflects the problem, especially when combined with the examination of the problem in my answer (imho).

Comment: Thank you, Deltics. I tried DateOf  and TimeOf. actually the assigning  of values with their use doesn't help.

Comment: @asd - what version of Delphi ?  I reproduced your problem exactly using XE5 and DateOf() / TimeOf() solved the problem as described.

Comment: @Deltics. Yes, `SameDateTime` solves the problem. That is why I accepted the answer of Ken White given yesterday. I appended my question on the consideration that assigning by `DateOf` and `TimeOf` will be enough. It is not in some cases

Comment: Personally I'd fix it without SameDateTime using exact comparison.

Comment: @Deltics The original code did not look like the code you spent the bulk of this answer dealing with. Asker was using DateOf and TimeOf. This is why the question should have been closed until an MCVE was produced.

Comment: @asd-tm `SameDateTime` **alone** does not solve the problem in XE5. Read again Deltics explanation regarding am and pm hours. Try setting `DT` with a time of, say, 23:20:00. You need to use both `SameDateTime`and `DateOf/TimeOf`.